# При установке игры 2 иконки Android

Tags: android, unity3d

При установке игры появляется 2 одинаковых иконки на андроиде. Обе запускают одно и то же приложение. 
Возможно, дело в манифесте, но манифестов от разных плагинов много.
Может, кто нибудь подскажет, в какую сторону надо копать? Где в манифесте такие строки? И в этом ли вообще дело?

Answer (score 2):

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Нужно избегать дублирования этих строк, юнити объединяет все манифесты в один из папки plugins/android, пытается смержить, вам надо только в одном оставить.